# Playing around with calloc() and free() in C

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, calloc

I'm playing around with `malloc`, `calloc`, and `free`, and I notice that the compiler sends me 3 warnings:

1. "Warning    C6011    Dereferencing NULL pointer 'ptr'." Line 20
2. "Warning    C4022    'free': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1" Line 20
3. "Warning    C4047    '=': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void pointer'" Line 21

Here's the code:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])
{
    int* ptr = NULL;
    int size_b = 30;
    int i = 0;

    ptr = (int*)calloc(size_b, sizeof(int));

    if (ptr)
    {
        printf("%d", ptr[0]);
    }

    for (i; i < size_b; ++i)
    {
        free(ptr[i]);    // Line 20
        ptr[i] = NULL;   // Line 21
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program runs but I'd like to know the source of these errors, and if there is a way of clearing them.

Comment: The argument to `free()` has to be a pointer. `ptr[i]` is an `int`, not a pointer.

Comment: Basically, the argument to `free()` has to be a pointer that was previously returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`. `ptr` is the only pointer like that, not `ptr[i]`.

Comment: What are you expecting this to do? When you allocate a block of memory you can only free the whole thing, you can't free individual elements of it.

Comment: "The program runs" is an illusion.  Lines 20 and 21 are [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: With no comments, we can't tell what you are expecting these lines of code to do. So it's hard to explain what's wrong with them.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a block of memory given to you at location `ptr` To free that memory, just do `free(ptr);` You don't deallocate word-by-word; the whole block gets allocated/free'd at once (unless you do `realloc` to do stuff piecewise).

Just replace

```
    for (i; i < size_b; ++i)
    {
        free(ptr[i]);    // Line 20
        ptr[i] = NULL;   // Line 21
    }
```

with

```
free(ptr);
```

Also you won't need `i` anymore. I'd also move the dellocation underneath the `if (ptr)` for safety.

Comment: I suspect you're probably closest to what the OP was misunderstanding: if you allocate a "block of ints", then you simply free "the block".  Not each individual int.

Comment: I was under the impression that each element had to be freed, I didn't know that it deallocates the whole block for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
free(ptr[i]);
```

the expression `ptr[i]` has the type `int` and the value of the object of the type `int` is `0`.

So the compiler issues the message

> "Warning C4022 'free': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1"

because it expects an object of the pointer type `void *` that points to the previously allocated memory instead of the type `int`.

Pay attention to that in this statement

```
ptr = (int*)calloc(size_b, sizeof(int));
```

there is allocated one single extent of memory (for an array of integers) the address of which is stored in the pointer `ptr`. So to free the allocated extent of memory you need to write

```
free( ptr );
```

Then in the next line you are trying to assign the null pointer constant `NULL` of the type `void *` to an object of the type `int`.

```
ptr[i] = NULL;
```

So the compiler issues the message

> "Warning C4047 '=': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void
> pointer'"

As for this message

> "Warning C6011 Dereferencing NULL pointer 'ptr'."

then it seems that due to the preceding if statement

```
if (ptr)
{
    printf("%d", ptr[0]);
}
```

the compiler thinks that if the control was passed after this if statement (as if there is an else statement) then the pointer `ptr` is equal to `NULL`.

Your program does not make a great sense. Nevertheless to make it correct you could change it for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    size_t n = 30;
    
    int *ptr = calloc( n, sizeof( int ) );

    if ( ptr )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", ptr[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( ptr );
}
```